# allow datepicker to pick values only upto two weeks from the start date

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#downpayment_date').datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', minDate: new Date(<?php echo $this->y;?>, <?php echo (($this->m) - 1);?>, <?php echo ($this->d);?>),
       beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
   });
});
</script>
```

Okay I have this datepicker that allows start date based on the value retrieved dynamically in PHP.

Is it possible to limit the selection of date to just two weeks from the startdate.

.i.e if the start date in the above datepicker starts from 08/12/2012, the datepicker should allow me to only select dates upto two weeks from that date.

```
      $('#downpayment_date').datepicker({
           dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', minDate: new Date(<?php echo $this->y;?>, <?php echo (($this->m) - 1);?>, <?php echo ($this->d);?>),
           maxDate:new Date(<?php echo $this->y;?>, <?php echo (($this->m) - 1);?>, <?php echo ($this->d)+14;?>),
           beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
       });
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MyMaxDate = $("#date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(<?php echo $y;?>, <?php echo ($m - 1);?>, <?php echo $d;?>),maxDate: MyMaxDate +14, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
});
```

Actually I found the above method bit more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing would be to pass in the PHP date and just add 14 days to it like this:

```
var start = '08/12/2012';
var dateArray = start.split('/');
$('#date').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(dateArray[2],dateArray[0]-1, dateArray[1], 0, 0, 0, 0),
    maxDate: new Date(dateArray[2],dateArray[0]-1, parseInt(dateArray[1])+14, 0, 0, 0, 0)
});
```

This handles dates across months and years just fine. Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3nSeb/)**. So instead of hard coding the start date as I do above, just echo the PHP date as you noted.

Comment: sure a pain creating the js date args from array when could just echo `strtotime()`

Comment: @charlietfl - I'd hardly call creating the above array a pain. Plus strtotime() creates a Unix timestamp which you'd need to manipulate anyway.

Comment: maxDate:new Date(<?php echo $this->y;?>, <?php echo (($this->m) - 1);?>, <?php echo ($this->d)+14,0,0,0,0;?>) ..this didnt work..

Comment: Just drop in the new date as you mentioned in your question and the jQuery will do the rest.

Comment: @j08691..i edited the code in my question to implement what you suggested, but that didnt work out..

Answer (score 0):

Use the maxDate attribute in the date picker and set it to minDate + 14

Comment: Wasn't able to test it at the time. Sorry about that